# Why does this change to the Array prototype not work in my jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-plugins, prototype

I have added the following method to the Array prototype:

```
Array.prototype.foreach = function(func){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
        if(!func(this[i]) === false) break; //return false from func in order to break the loop
    }
    return this;
}
```

In the same file, *after* the above code, I have the following jQuery plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.addClassForEvents = function(){

    var that = this;

    arguments.foreach(function(event){
        that.bind(event[0], function(){
            that.addClass(event[0]);
        })
        .bind(event[1], function(){
            that.removeClass(event[0]);
        });
    });

    return this;
}
```

In order to use this jQuery plugin, my code would look something like:

```
$('div').addClassForEvents(['mouseenter', 'mouseleave']);
```

However, the browser throws an error on the "arguments.foreach(...." line of the jQuery plugin, stating simply that

> Object # has no method 'foreach'

Yet the `foreach` method works in other places of my code. Why is it undefined within this jQuery plugin?

Comment: Why do you break your loop (and foreach), when the function returns a truthy value?

Comment: That's actually a mistake (just look at my comment next to that line of code!). Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: That still does not make much sense within a foreach function/method.…

Comment: Why is that? Seems like providing a way to break out of a loop is pretty standard.

Comment: Common understanding is that foreach iterates over every element of a collection. I don't know of a language, where a foreach method breaks out if the applied function returns false. Feel free to prove me wrong

Comment: Since JavaScript doesn't provide a native implementation of a foreach loop, I created one. And like all other foreach loops in every other programming language, I wanted a way to break the loop. If you've got a better way of accomplishing this, I'd love to see/adopt it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7146/discussion-between-knittl-and-maxedison)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't work because arguments isn't an array. Its an (array-like) arguments object.

[Explanation from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)

You can convert it to an array using slice in modern browsers (and by actually looping in IE).

```
var argArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
```

Comment: You can convert it to an array using slice in IE too

Comment: @AngusC You could be correct. I have a generic function that does this and there are definitely some array-like objects that IE doesn't like to call slice on.

Answer (score 4):

`arguments` is not an array, but an object. For example it provides properties such as `arguments.callee` and `arguments.caller`.

You can use foreach of the Array prototype by calling `apply` on it (cf. [The JavaScript arguments object…and beyond](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/javascripts-arguments-object-and-beyond/)):

> Since all the methods of Array.prototype are designed to be generic they can be easily applied to the array-compatible arguments object:

```
jQuery.fn.addClassForEvents = function(){

    var that = this;

    [].foreach.apply(arguments, (function(event){
        that.bind(event[0], function(){
            that.addClass(event[0]);
        })
        .bind(event[1], function(){
            that.removeClass(event[0]);
        });
    });

    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn the arguments **object** into an **array**

Try this:

```
jQuery.fn.addClassForEvents = function(){

    var that = this, arg = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    arg.foreach(function(event){
        that.bind(event[0], function(){
            that.addClass(event[0]);
        })
        .bind(event[1], function(){
            that.removeClass(event[0]);
        });
    });

    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert the `arguments` to an array, you can use the `jQuery.makeArray(arguments)` too...

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/